# Using declarative-authorization's "without_access_control"with Cucumber's @javascript

Tags: javascript, cucumber, capybara, rack, declarative-authorization

I have the following in my `features/support/env.rb` file:

```
require 'declarative_authorization/maintenance'
World(Authorization::TestHelper)
```

I have this in a feature file:

```
When I view the list of users
Then I see the list of users page
```

And this in a steps file:

```
When /^I view the list of users$/ do
  without_access_control{ visit users_path }
end

Then /^I see the list of users page$/ do
  current_path.should eq(users_path)
end
```

All runs fine until I tag the feature `@javascript`, then I get the error:

```
expected: "/users"
got: "/users/sign_in"
```

Can anyone tell me how to respect `without_access_control` when running in `@javascript` mode?

I think another way of asking the same question is **how do I get Declarative Authorization's built in test-helper `without_access_control` to work with `rack_test`, when `js=true`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General consensus seems to be this isn't possible but will update if someone proves me wrong!